# Java color object and mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have stored color objects in MongoDB and it is stored like this:

```
"color" : { "value" : -16777216, "falpha" : 0 }
```

I have stored some color objects and this is the result:

```
-327680 ->  new Color(251,0, 0); 
-262144 ->  new Color(252, 0, 0);
-196608 ->  new Color(253, 0, 0); 
-131072 ->  new Color(254, 0, 0);
-16777216 ->  new Color(0, 0, 0);
```

My question now would be what is the connection between e.g. this color object:

`new Color(251,0, 0)`

and the number

`-327680`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert following decimal numbers, representing each color channel:

- `255` - **alpha channel** (*opacity*)
- `251` - **red**
- `0` - **green**
- `0` - **blue**

Into byte-sized binary numbers, you get:

- `1111 1111` - **alpha**
- `1111 1011` - **red**
- `0000 0000` - **green**
- `0000 0000` - **blue**

Then if you concatenate them into one 4-byte signed integer you get:

`1111 1111 1111 1011 0000 0000 0000 0000` <kbd>BIN</kbd>

which equals:

`-327680` <kbd>DEC</kbd>

in decimal.

The result is negative because of [signed number representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).
Same goes for the rest of numbers:

- `1111 1111 1111 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000` <kbd>BIN</kbd> = `-262144` <kbd>DEC</kbd>
- `1111 1111 1111 1101 0000 0000 0000 0000` <kbd>BIN</kbd> = `-196608` <kbd>DEC</kbd>
- `1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` <kbd>BIN</kbd> = `-16777216` <kbd>DEC</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Is there an onlie converter?

Comment: I used standard windows calculator in programmer mode to convert the numbers but you can try using this one:
http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=045049054055055055050049054